# PHP-CS-FIXER is ignoring my config

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, psr-2, php-cs-fixer

I have created a file called `.gm_cs` in the root of my project and `php-cs-fixer` is installed globally.

In the config file is the following

```
<?php
 $rules = array(
     '@PSR2' => true,
     'combine_consecutive_unsets' => true,
     'no_extra_consecutive_blank_lines' => array('break', 'continue', 'extra', 'return', 'throw', 'use', 'parenthesis_brace_block', 'square_brace_block', 'curly_brace_block'),
     'no_useless_else' => true,
     'no_useless_return' => true,
     'ordered_class_elements' => true,
     'array_syntax' => array('syntax' => 'short'),
     'ordered_imports' => true,
     'phpdoc_add_missing_param_annotation' => true,
     'psr4' => true,
     'strict_comparison' => true,
     'strict_param' => true,
 );

 $fixers = array(
     '-pre_increment'
 );

 return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()->setRiskyAllowed(false)->setRules($rules)->fixers($fixers)->in(__DIR__);
```

I am calling the command from git-bash on windows with the following:
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config-file=gm_cs`

I have also tried these:
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config-file=.gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config-file=./.gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config .gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config ./.gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config=gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config=.gm_cs`
`php-cs-fixer fix -vvv ./private --config=./.gm_cs`

In desperation I copied the `.php_cs` from my composer/vendor folder:

```
<?php
Symfony\CS\Fixer\Contrib\HeaderCommentFixer::setHeader($header);

return Symfony\CS\Config::create()
    // use default SYMFONY_LEVEL and extra fixers:
    ->fixers(array(
        '-pre_increment',
    ))
    ->finder(
        Symfony\CS\Finder::create()
            ->exclude('Symfony/CS/Tests/Fixtures')
            ->in(__DIR__)
    )
;
```

And reduced the fixers to just stop the pre-increment one, and then ran it with all the commands listed previously, and it still hasn't solved the issue.

More than anything else, I just want it to stop swapping the `$i++` to `++$i` because this is a massive project I have inherited and I don't have time to test all those changes yet (no unit tests exist yet).

Any advice or help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the version of `php-cs-fixer` I am using is the `Symfony\CS\Fixer\` one, and it doesn't take `$rules`.

Additionally, the file needs to be named `.php_cs`

Comment: Which version one are you using?

Comment: Probably 1.x, it was renamed in 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony independent example: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/m9yq/creating-a-standalone-composer-json-library-or-package

**.php_cs**

```
return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setUsingCache(false)
    ->setRules([
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'ordered_imports' => true,
    ])
    ->setFinder(
        PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
            ->exclude(['bin', 'vendor'])
            ->in(__DIR__)
    );
```

Symfony dependent example:

**.php_cs**

```
$finder = Symfony\CS\Finder::create()
    ->exclude(['app', 'spec', 'build', 'bin', 'web', 'vendor'])
    ->in(__DIR__);

return  Symfony\CS\Config::create()
    ->fixers(['short_array_syntax', '-phpdoc_align', 'ordered_use'])
    ->finder($finder);
```

Example without **.php_cs** file:

```
$ bin/php-cs-fixer fix src --fixers=short_array_syntax
```